# how to set the vibration with UILocalNotification and also sound will not come only vibrate the iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, vibration

I have stuck in a problem that in my alarm application for that i m creating a local notification and in my app there is a vibration on/off button when user on the vibration at that time only iPhone should vibrate sound will not come and when user off the vibration at that time only iPhone sound should come not vibrate.
       Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

```
if(isVibrationButtonOn)
{
   AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
}
```

Dont forget to import

```
AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h
```

Edit: In case of Local notification and vibration, You can refer the following discussions.

[SO POST 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110235/ios-local-notification-custom-vibration-or-vibrate-for-longer-duration)

[SO POST 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443848/uilocalnotification-not-working-no-vibration-on-iphone-4-ios-4-3)

Comment: In case of notification, if app is in background then it will behave according to the user settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use use these two:

```
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

Also add AudioToolbox.framework and import it.

Comment: will it work when localnotification fire and app is in background.